Is there any way to find the gird path in Minimum Path Sum
Minimum Path Sum:
Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right, which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.
Input: grid = [[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]
Output: 7
Explanation: Because the path 1 → 3 → 1 → 1 → 1 minimizes the sum.
Is there any way to print out the path 1 → 3 → 1 → 1 → 1 in Python
I'm having trouble it print out the path instead of the sum. I'm thinking about BFS but my solution doesn't include the calculation of the weights
def bfs(grid):
    queue = collections.deque([[(0,0)]])
    seen = set([(0,0)])
    while queue:
        path = queue.popleft()
        x, y = path[-1]
        if (x,y) == (width-1, height-1):
            return path
        for x2, y2 in ((x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)):
            if 0 <= x2 < width and 0 <= y2 < height and (x2, y2) not in seen:
                queue.append(path + [(x2, y2)])
                seen.add((x2, y2))


Indeed, a BFS algorithm does not minimise the sum of the path. It finds the path with the minimum number of steps, not the minimum cost. Hence, it will always return the path that first goes all the way right and then all the way down, no matter what the values are in grid[y][x].
Your code checks all four neighbors of a cell, while the LeetCode problem you linked to only allows moves to the right and downward moves. I suppose you did this intentionally and want to solve problems where all four moves are allowed.
You could check your solution with a less trivial grid, where the optimal path is not that straightforward, like this one:
grid = [
    [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
    [19, 17, 15, 13,  9,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  7,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  5,  1,  5,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  7,  1,  1,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  9, 11, 13, 15],
    [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
    [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  1],
]

You can turn your BFS code into an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm:

Use a binary heap instead of a queue
Don't push the complete paths in that heap, but just the coordinates of the last point on the path, but including the cost, so that the root of the heap is guaranteed to have the point with the least cost (to reach from the starting point)
Convert seen to a dictionary, where the corresponding value is the point from where you came when visiting the keyed point. With that information you'll have a linked list of points that represents the best path. You can derive it once you are at the target position.

Here is your code adapted with those changes:
from heapq import heappush, heappop 

def dijkstra(grid):
    height = len(grid)
    width = len(grid[0])
    # A heap instead of a queue:
    heap = [(0,0,0)]  # (cost, x, y)
    # a dict instead of a set
    seen = { (0,0): None }  
    while heap:
        cost, x, y = heappop(heap)
        if (x, y) == (width-1, height-1):
            # Get path from seen:
            path = [(x, y)]
            while seen[(x, y)]:
                x, y = seen[(x, y)]
                path.append((x, y))
            return cost, path[::-1]  # return cost and path
        for x2, y2 in ((x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)):
            if 0 <= x2 < width and 0 <= y2 < height and (x2, y2) not in seen:
                heappush(heap, (cost + grid[y2][x2], x2, y2))
                seen[(x2, y2)] = (x, y)

This returns both the cost and the path.
As stated, the LeetCode problem you linked to, limits the moves you can make to only right and down -- which is a different problem from what you are trying to solve it seems. Also, it expects you to only return the minimum cost, not the path, so then you'd not need to convert seen to a dict, nor to build the path at the end.
For the LeetCode version of the problem you can use dynamic programming instead of Dijkstra's algorithm.

If elements in the grid are processed row-by-row and for each row, column-by-column, we need only make a single pass through the grid. That is because the shortest path (where distances are costs) from the upper-left corner (the origin, indexed [0, 0]) to any element [i, j] depends only on the shortest paths from the origin to the elements [i-1, j] and [i, j-1], both of which are computed before element [i, j] is examined.
The following code is Ruby, but with some remarks I will make it can be viewed as pseudo-code.
Code
def opt(grid)
  m = grid.size
  n = grid[0].size
  best = Array.new(m) { Array.new(n) }

  m.times do |i|
    n.times do |j|
      if i == 0
        if j == 0
          h = { prev: nil, val: 0 }
        else # j > 0
          h = { prev: [i,j-1], val: best[i][j-1][:val] } 
        end
      else # i > 0
        h = { prev: [i-1,j], val: best[i-1][j][:val] } 
        if j > 0 && best[i][j-1][:val] < h[:val]
          h = { prev: [i,j-1], val: best[i][j-1][:val] } 
        end  
      end      
      h[:val] += grid[i][j]
      best[i][j] = h
    end
  end
  best
end

best = Array.new(m) { Array.new(n) } creates a two-dimensional array with m = grid.size rows and n = grid[0].size columns. best[i][j] is the value of best at row index i and column index j.
Each element best[i][j] holds a hash (a.k.a hashmap or dictionary) with keys :prev and :val. The value of :prev (best[i][j][:prev]) gives the row and column indices of the element that precedes the given element on a shortest path from the origin to the given element. The value of :val (best[i][j][:val])is the minimum cost along a feasible path (i.e., each move is to the right or down) from [0, 0] to that element.
h[:val] += grid[i][j] and then best[i][j] = h adds the cost of element [i, j] into the minimum cost from [0, 0] to element [i, j].
Example
Suppose
grid = [
  [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
  [19, 17, 13, 17],
  [ 1,  1,  3,  1],
  [ 1,  1,  8,  3],
  [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
  [ 1,  1, 13, 15]
]  

Then
best = opt(grid)
  #=> [
  [{:prev=>nil, :val=>1}, {:prev=>[0, 0], :val=>2},
   {:prev=>[0, 1], :val=>3}, {:prev=>[0, 2], :val=>4}],
  [{:prev=>[0, 0], :val=>20}, {:prev=>[0, 1], :val=>19},
   {:prev=>[0, 2], :val=>16}, {:prev=>[0, 3], :val=>21}],
  [{:prev=>[1, 0], :val=>21}, {:prev=>[1, 1], :val=>20},
   {:prev=>[1, 2], :val=>19}, {:prev=>[2, 2], :val=>20}],
  [{:prev=>[2, 0], :val=>22}, {:prev=>[2, 1], :val=>21},
   {:prev=>[2, 2], :val=>27}, {:prev=>[2, 3], :val=>23}], 
  [{:prev=>[3, 0], :val=>23}, {:prev=>[3, 1], :val=>22},
   {:prev=>[4, 1], :val=>23}, {:prev=>[3, 3], :val=>24}],
  [{:prev=>[4, 0], :val=>24}, {:prev=>[4, 1], :val=>23},
   {:prev=>[4, 2], :val=>36}, {:prev=>[4, 3], :val=>39}]
]

Recovering the optimal solution
I have not provided code to recover the optimal solution, but that is straightforward, as I will illustrate with the example above.
We begin by examining the value of best for the last row and last column (the shortest path destination).
m = grid.size
  #=> 6
n = grid.size
  #=> 4
best[m-1][n-1] = best[5][3]
  #=> {:prev=>[4, 3], :val=>39}

This tells us that shortest path from the the origin to the destination (at index [5, 3]) has a length of 39 and the next-to-last element on that path was [4, 3] (above [5, 3]).
We then examine, in turn,
best[4][3] #=> {:prev=>[3, 3], :val=>24}
best[3][3] #=> {:prev=>[2, 3], :val=>23}
best[2][3] #=> {:prev=>[2, 2], :val=>20}
best[2][2] #=> {:prev=>[1, 2], :val=>19}
best[1][2] #=> {:prev=>[0, 2], :val=>16}
best[0][2] #=> {:prev=>[0, 1], :val=>3}
best[0][1] #=> {:prev=>[0, 0], :val=>2}
best[0][0] #=> {:prev=>nil, :val=>1}

The optimal path is therefore
[0,0]->[0,1]->[0,2]->[1,2]->[2,2]->[2,3]->[3,3]->[4,3]->[5,3]

